# Is the object itself optimized out when I use this RAII-style pattern?

Tags: c++, arm, microcontroller, raii, cortex-m

There is a RAII-style C++ pattern that implements scope-based ownership by creating a class that has no member and relying on the class's constructor and destructor (and the fact that the destructor is automatically called when the function returns). For example, the standard `std::lock_guard` implements this pattern.

I'm programming an EFM32 ARM Cortex-M microcontroller and came up with this class which uses a similar style:

```
#include <em_int.h>

class InterruptGuard final {

public:

    explicit inline InterruptGuard() {
        INT_Disable();
    }

    InterruptGuard(const InterruptGuard &other) = delete;

    InterruptGuard(const InterruptGuard &&other) = delete;

    inline ~InterruptGuard() {
        INT_Enable();
    }

    InterruptGuard &operator=(const InterruptGuard &other) = delete;

    InterruptGuard &operator=(const InterruptGuard &&other) = delete;

};
```

So if I want to disable interrupts inside a function with multiple return statements, I can make sure that they are going to be re-enabled without me worrying about explicitly re-enabling them at every return statement.

NOTE: the `INT_Enable` and `INT_Disable` functions [implement a counter](http://devtools.silabs.com/dl/documentation/doxygen/4.3.0/ezr32wg/html/group__INT.html) so `INT_Enable` will do the right thing and only enable interrupts when they really need to be enabled. So this class should be properly nestable.

```
void func() {
    InterruptGuard guard;

    // ...
}
```

My question is:

When I use this pattern, is the compiler going to do "the right thing" here and optimize out the object (so that no memory is actually consumed by this class) and just inline the `INT_Enable` and `INT_Disable` calls to the function that uses the `InterruptGuard` class?

Comment: Probably. The only way to tell for sure is to look at the generated code.

Comment: There's actually no memory occupied by `InterruptGuard`, so what should be optimized out?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ `Why? sizeof(InterruptGuard)` must be non-zero, and you could take the address of `guard`.

Comment: Just because sizeof(InterruptGuard) is non-zero does not mean that it will take up one or more bytes of storage, by itself.

Comment: One comment on your class implementation:   it isn't nest-able and will turn on interrupts upon exit even if they weren't on at entry.  You should really have an 'old state' member variable that is gotten at construction and restored at destruction so that the IRQ state is preserved.

Comment: @RussSchultz Actually, `INT_Enable` and `INT_Disable` implement a counter, so it is nestable.

See: http://devtools.silabs.com/dl/documentation/doxygen/4.3.0/ezr32wg/html/group__INT.html

Comment: what the point to make default ctor explicit? Is the target to put as much redundant keywords as possible (including inline)?

Comment: @Slava What do you mean? Is it wrong?

Comment: @Venemo I did not say it is wrong. It is redundant - explicit for default ctor does not mean anything. Ctor and dtor is already inline. Move ctor is not there because you have copy ctor etc etc.

Comment: @Venemo   Ah, I see that.  One thing to note is if you do something like `class DisableIRQ
{
    int oldstate;
public:
    DisableIRQ() { oldstate = __disable_irq();};
    ~DisableIRQ() { if(!oldstate) __enable_irq();};
};` The previous state ends up on the stack, and the inline code is a little smaller (since it doesn't need to fetch and increment a counter)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Compiling](https://gcc.godbolt.org/) with `g++ -std=c++1y -O3 -Werror -Wextra` (gcc version 5.3.0) this code:

```
#include <cstdio>

class InterruptGuard final {

public:

    explicit inline InterruptGuard() {
        printf("enable\n");
    }

    InterruptGuard(const InterruptGuard &other) = delete;

    InterruptGuard(const InterruptGuard &&other) = delete;

    inline ~InterruptGuard() {
        printf("disable\n");
    }

    InterruptGuard &operator=(const InterruptGuard &other) = delete;

    InterruptGuard &operator=(const InterruptGuard &&other) = delete;

};

int main()
{
    InterruptGuard i;
}
```

and this code:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
  printf("enable\n");
  printf("disable\n");
}
```

gives the same assembly in both cases:

```
.LC0:
        .string "enable"
.LC1:
        .string "disable"
main:
        subq    $8, %rsp
        movl    $.LC0, %edi
        call    puts
        movl    $.LC1, %edi
        call    puts
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        addq    $8, %rsp
        ret
```

Comment: Here is the [arm version](https://godbolt.org/g/GiHFR4) as the OP is using.  Note that this RAII gives no control over when interrupts are enable/disabled and lets the compiler figure it out.  This can increase interrupt latency in many cases.  RAII is great for care where execution time doesn't matter.  You can solve this with block scoping where you want interrupts disabled; the object should only exist for the block.